# Does cosine similarity imply collinearity even for Hilbert spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

If two vectors are cosine similar, that is the angle between them is 0, then the vectors are collinear. For Non-zero vectors, then one vector is the scalar multiple of the other.

Does this still apply to general Hilbert spaces? If not, then in which function spaces and what inner products can we conclude that one function is a scalar multiple of the other if they're cosine similar?

edit: i.e are functions $f$ and $g$ scalar multiples of each other when $$\frac{\langle f,g \rangle}{\lVert f \rVert \lVert g \rVert}=1$$

Comment: do you mean when you have equality in the cauchy schwarz inequality?

Comment: @Timkinsella I mean if $\frac{\langle f,g \rangle}{\lVert f \rVert \lVert g \rVert}=1$

Comment: google the phrase "equality in the cauchy schwarz inequality" and stuff should come up

Comment: @Timkinsella thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is true that $f$ and $g$ are necessarily multiples of each other if
$$
\left|\frac{\langle f, g \rangle}{\|f\|\|g\|}\right| = 1 .
$$
This result is sometimes referred to as the "equality case" of the [Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

More generally, the CBS inequality states that $|\langle f, g \rangle| \leq \|f\|\|g\|$, which is equivalent to saying that the cosine similarity always has absolute value less than or equal to $1$. The result regarding the equality case is that $|\langle f,g \rangle| = \|f\|\,\|g\|$ if and only if $f$ and $g$ are scalar multiples of each other.

Comment: Thank you so much!